# Local web proxy à la Privoxy?

Tags: proxy, filter

I'd like to filter some web sites I visit by running a local web proxy like Privoxy to get rid of the ads and simplify the layout.

Does someone know of a good web proxy for Android?

Answer (score 1):

As ce4 pointed out, Privoxy just seems have to left the playstore within the last month. At the moment, the probably only candidate left seems to be [FilterProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=KRIS.android.FilterProxy).

On the other hand, if you have your device rooted, there are some additional possibilities working by manipulating the device's local hosts file. A quite good candidate in that case would be [AdAway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adaway), with the alternative of using [AdFree](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigtincan.android.adfree) and several other candidates.

Comment: Thanks for the infos. I'd rather stay with the standard Samsung firmware for the time being. I'll check FilterProxy.

Comment: @Gulbahar: rooting the device does not necessarily mean using a non-standard firmware, (though in practice it may be more or less difficult depending on the model).

Answer (score 0):

There has been a port of Privoxy for Android, it was available in the Play Store but has been deleted: Old and broken [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.galoula.Privoxy) link.

The author's site has a page still [here](http://android.galoula.com/en/Privoxy/) but no downloadalbe .apk.

You might have luck by asking him for an .apk. I don't know of any other port, alas.